# Смена типа клавиатуры у EditText'а

Tags: android, kotlin

Подскажите, в `xml` у `edittext`'а пишу: `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`, но эта клавиатура не отображается. 
PS: пишу на kotlin

Comment: Если пишете в XML разметке, какая разница что за язык? :)

Comment: такое может быть если клавиатура не стоковая, сторонняя

Comment: Проверьте как работает на эмуляторе.

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `android:inputType` лишь указывает какого типа символы принимает контрол, соответственно система под этот фильтр подбирает нужную клавиатуру.

Но непосредственно за появление клавиатуры он не отвечает.